# Relate two entities via a third one

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to figure it out how to relate two entities using another one they both have in common. My model is the following:

```
A Customer has a list of Codes
A Promotion has a list of Codes
A Code has a list of Customers and a list of Promotions
```

I would like to add to the Promotion Entity a list of Customers. This list would include all customers who at least have the same codes as in the promotion (can have more). Ideally I would like to model this a field but I am not sure if this is possible. I have found no information.

Can it be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, so, what is the problem, you need a join query....Post how have you mapped these guys in Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can define

1. Customer Entity.
2. Code entity which has  @ManyToMany relationship with Customer.   ( This is required if customer can have code even when there is no promotion.)
3. Promotion Entity which has @ManyToMany relationship with Customer 
   and @ManyToMany with Code.

Comment: The ManyToMany with the Customer has to be based on the condition they have all codes to included in the promotion (if a promotion has 10, the customer must have at least those then to be a customer of the promotion). It is therefore not a conventional ManyToMany I belive, unless there is a way to map what I am saying with this condition.

Comment: You are probably mixing the business rule with your entity relationship design.

Answer (score -1):

At the end I ended up doing the following

```
public Set<Customers> getCustomers(){
    Set<Customers> customers = null;
    for (Code c : codes)
        if(customers == null)
            customers = c.getCustomers();
        else
            customers.retainAll(c.getCustomers());


    return customers;
}
```

I do a Eager retrieve for the Codes, and in the codes an Eager retrieve for the Customers. So far is performing well, but I would prefer this to be all calculated in the DBMS and not on the controller side. Still have not find a nice way to to it.